# Cannot create a simple entity with Nestjs TypeOrm and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, nestjs-typeorm

I want to create an entity which called 'topic' , but i have a problem and i dont't understand it,
when i try to create the entity topic on postman like that:
{
"title:" :"Physique"
}
I found this error :  ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] null value in column "title" of relation "topic" violates not-null constraint.
This is my code.
File TopicService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TopicEntity } from './entities/topic.entity/topic.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { AddTopicDto } from './dto/add-topic.tdo';

@Injectable()
export class TopicService {
    constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TopicEntity)
    private topicRepository: Repository<TopicEntity>,
  ) {}
  async addTopic(topic: AddTopicDto): Promise<TopicEntity> {
    return await this.topicRepository.save(topic);
  }
}
```

TopicController :

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TopicService } from './topic.service';
import { TopicEntity } from './entities/topic.entity/topic.entity';
import { AddTopicDto } from './dto/add-topic.tdo';

@Controller('topic')
export class TopicController {
  constructor(    
    private topicService: TopicService,
) {}
  @Post()
  async addTopic(@Body() addTopicDto: AddTopicDto): Promise<TopicEntity> {
    return await this.topicService.addTopic(addTopicDto);
  }
}
```

TopicEntity :

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
@Entity('topic')
export class TopicEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  title: string;
  @CreateDateColumn({ default: new Date() })
  createdAt?: Date;
  @CreateDateColumn({ default: new Date() })
  UpdatedAt?: Date;
```

TopicEntityDto :

```
import { IS_ALPHA, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';
export class AddTopicDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  title: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting the request to create a subject in Postman, it appears that you have a little typo in your JSON object. The definition of the "title" field has to be changed. Use `"title"` (in double quotes) in place of the word `'title:'` as follows:

```
{
  "title": "Physique"
}
```

Currently, the colon is enclosed by double quotes, which results in an error since the colon is not being recognised as a field name separator but rather as a component of the field name. You have defined the "title" field and its value correctly by enclosing the complete field name in double quotes: "Physique." You should no longer have the `null value` error after doing this.

Comment: oh yes! I did not pay attention thank you very much